# Unable to Login

Tags: ee2, login

For some reason I am not able to log into my EE Control Panel this morning. I was working on it last night without difficulty and this morning when I try and log in the username and password are cleared out of the fields and it comes back with empty fields. I have tried this in Safari and Firefox with the same result. This also happens with another user on the site. I am running EE 2.9.0.

Edit: I am seeing an unusually long session id at the end of the URL after trying to login:

Normal looking URL & session ID:

> http://domainname.com/admin.php?/cp/homepage?S=2eb7686aa8a34e593cc97a79ff27c30f

What I am seeing with failed login:

> http://dev.domainanme.com/admin.php?/cp/login&return=Qz1hZGRvbnNfbW9kdWxlcyZhbXA7TT1zaG93X21vZHVsZV9jcCZhbXA7bW9kdWxlPXJlcHVibGljX2FuYWx5dGljcw==

Has anyone else had similar experience? If so, what is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in an [older EE bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19334).

> To resolve I had to disable the ‘cp_member_login’ hook in the
>   extensions table where the ‘class’ value is ‘Republic_analytics_ext’

After that was disabled I was able to log in.